# How would Outlook handle my PST concerns?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pop3

This is a real quick question regarding POP email in Outlook essentially.

I'm going to recreate my POP email profile based on some advice from my mailhost, due to emails I send being constantly sent again and again and again.

Now at the moment, all my POP3 mail is stored in a .PST file. This is fine, I will leave that in my Outlook so I have access to all my old sent items still for business purposes.

When I create my new account in Outlook for POP, can I point it to my old .PST or must I create a new one? And in either scenario, will it redownload all my mail again from the server, or am I right in thinking that once you have downloaded mail using POP from the server, it won't download it again? Meaning I will only get new mail that hasn't yet been downloaded into my new PST (or the existing one if you can do that).

Thanks!

Comment: In your original settings, did you have the account set to leave a copy of all the mail on the server?  Because whether or not all your mail is still there depends on the settings you chose.

Comment: Yes I did, it's set for 14days to be retained.

Comment: Then you can get the last 14 days of emails again from the server.

Comment: So if I point my new account to the old .PST, it will download the last 14days of my mail again even though its all in my PST already?

Comment: -1   Your subject made it look like this is a question about POP3 generally. But no, it's about Outlook and outlook's PST files.

Comment: Apologies for the misleading title post Barlop. Maybe you can offer some advice on the query? and thanks Bon Gart for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I create my new account in Outlook for POP, can I point it to my old .PST or must I create a new one?

When you create a new e-mail account, you can choose whether to create a new PST-file or use an existing one.

> And in either scenario, will it redownload all my mail again from the server, or am I right in thinking that once you have downloaded mail using POP from the server, it won't download it again?

As @BonGart says, this depends on your settings. In general when using POP3 the e-mails are deleted from the server, but if you've configured to retain the e-mails for 14 days, those e-mails will probably be downloaded again.

One option could be to create a new PST-file for the new account, delete any duplicate e-mails downloaded twice, and then move all the e-mails from the old PST-file to the new one (you can in Outlook have several PST-files open simultaneously and drag-and-drop e-mails and folders between them).